# Как сделать встроенный в .net core сертификат доверенным в Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Сгенерировал стандартное `asp.net core` приложение по шаблону `mvc` в Linux Mint 19. При запуске все запросы автоматически перенаправляются на `https://localhost:5001`. Оказывается, начиная с версии 2.1 в .net core есть встроенный сертификат для https. Браузеры firefox и chrome отказываются принимать этот сертификат как доверенный, считая его самоподписанным. Как сделать этот сертификат доверенным?

Сам сертификат находится в директории `~/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my`. Имеет расширение `.pfx`. Генерируется командой `dotnet dev-certs https`. Для Windows и Mac есть команда, которая делает его доверенным в системе, - `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`. В Linux она не работает, нет такого флага, что собственно написано и в документации.

Читал, что для того чтобы сделать самоподписанный сертификат доверенным в Linux, нужно добавить файл сертификата в формате `.crt` в директорию `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`, и выполнить `sudo update-ca-certificates`. А потом импортировать сертификат в браузеры. Сконвертировал сертификат в `.crt`, добавил в хранилище, обновил конфигурацию, импортировал в браузеры, - не помогло. Уточню, при стандартном импорте в браузеры, нельзя указать директорию начинающуюся с точки. Так как сертификат лежит в `~/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my`, то я не могу указать этот каталог. Поэтому копировал сертификат в папку проекта, и импортировал оттуда.

Comment: указать директорию с точкой можно либо по ctrl+L либо по ctrl+H

Comment: Сработало, благодарю. Добавил сертификат в хранилище доверенных. Импортировал в браузеры. Сертификат по-прежнему помечен как не доверенный.

Меня смущает то, что приходится конвертировать сертификат в формат `.crt`. Linux не импортирует `.pfx`, а браузеры не импортируют `.crt`. Может это как то влияет.